# Wrong timestamp in plot, because of UTC+2

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some data which has a the following timestam as example:

```
2019-08-07 06:00:00.066768+02:00
```

Now I'm trying to plot the data from 6am to 6pm

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.loc['2019-08-07 06:00':'2019-08-07 18:00', 'Voltage L1-N in V'])
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage)')
ax.set_title('Phasenspannung L1')
# Set x-axis major ticks to two-hourly interval
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator( interval=2))
# Format x-tick labels as 24h format hour
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H Uhr'));
```

But the plot has the wrong x-axis labels. Instead of 06 Uhr to 18 Uhr it has a 2 hours offset. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the Problem by replacing the last line the following way:

```
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%H Uhr")
formatter.set_tzinfo(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```